# python: reducer with existing mapper

Tags: python, mapreduce

Right now, my mapper works correctly. I want to be able to **write a reducer** that takes my *links, host* output from this and  produces a unique list of them, so combining the keys from this mapper I guess?

```
for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()
        result = re.findall(r'<a href="(.*?)"', line)

        for word in result:
                print word + "\t" + Host #host is defined earlier as the first line of stdi
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What are you talking about? Where is your mapper function?

Comment: @m170897017 my mapper function is the code I provided, that is all of it..